# How can I bcc with mailx?

Tags: email, exim, mail-command, mailx

I'm trying to send unix `mail` (`heirloom-mailx`) via bcc.

```
$ mail -V
12.5 6/20/10
```

My MTA is exim, which sends via Gmail SMTP.

I can execute the following:

```
echo -e "body" | mail -s 'subject' -b hidden1@server.com,hidden2@server.com visible@server.com
```

All addresses receive the email, however the bcc is not hidden. i.e. in the email to `hidden1@server.com`, I still see:

```
To: visible@server.com
Bcc: hidden1@server.com,hidden2@server.com
```

How can I make `mail` send bcc properly?

Comment: I found this thread on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521280/send-mail-from-linux-command-line-using-bcc-and-from-headers

Comment: @slm Thanks. I did come across a few other posts complaining that `-b` didn't work, but they seemed to suggest that it wouldn't send at all, rather than the problem I have. However, if I don't get a response here, I'll check out some of the other mail programs.

Comment: Could you name MTA server you use? [sendmail/postfix/exim/...] I think that many servers strip `Bcc:` headers.

Comment: I'm using exim, which sends via gmail smtp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

heirloom-mailx hardcodes the options to pass to `/usr/sbin/sendmail`, and unfortunately the ones it passes don't make `Bcc:` headers work right in exim. That isn't really fixable, without patching and recompiling it. (You need to have it add `-t` to the arguments, and then either not pass the list of email addresses or alternatively set `extract_addresses_remove_arguments = false` in your exim config).

There is an easier solution: just have it send via SMTP. You do this by setting the `smtp` option, and since you've got a local MTA running, you should be able to set it to `localhost`. You can test like this:

```
$ mail -S smtp=localhost -s 'test message' -b other@domain.com email@domain.com
la la la
.
```

If that works, you can put the smtp option in `/etc/nail.rc` (system-wide) or `~/.mailrc` (per-user). Note that `nail.rc`, with an *n*, is not a typo.

Comment: Oh! That was surprisingly straightforward. I previously set up gmail smtp with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` and modifying `/etc/exim4/passwd.client`. How should I revert these changes, and how do they relate to `/etc/nail.rc`?

Comment: @Sparhawk There is no reason to revert your exim4-config changes. nail.rc just configures heirloom-mailx, and in this case you're just configuring it to speak to your local exim a different way (over a TCP connection to localhost vs. running /usr/sbin/sendmail)

Answer (score 5):

If using `GNU mailx` from `mailutils` package, BCC and CC can be added by using the `--append` option to add header variables, like so:

```
$ echo -e "body text line1\nline2\n\nsent at: $(date)" | mailx --append='FROM:Foghorn Leghorn <fleghorn@sender-domain.com>' --append='BCC:recipient1@acme.com' -s "test subject" -- recipient@acme.com mickey@mouse.com minnie@mouse.com
```

Also note how the above command uses the header variable for the FROM address.

Comment: Hi, I'm not really in the position to test this any more, but thank you for answering (+1)!

Comment: @Sparhawk: that's okay, I _do_ test all my responses :)

Comment: I more meant that for me to +1, I really should verify that "this answer is useful [to me]", but since I cannot, I gave you the benefit of the doubt.