# -c and -b options not working in mailx in ubuntu

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, io-redirection, mailx, mail-command

I was trying to send a mail from the shell script using the command

```
mailx -s "TEST MAIL" -c "user_name ..." user<message.txt
```

but it generates an error as unrecognized option `-c` ,the same happens if i 
use `-b` as a option for blind copy, so what options do i need to use for cc and bcc here ???

Comment: See  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445229/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/285415/117549; one of those may work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian and Ubuntu have replaced Heirloom `mailx` with s-nail `mailx`.  Both support the `-b` and `-c` options.  But there are other `mailx` commands from other packages which do not.

I suspect that you, too, are unknowingly using the GNU Mailutils `mailx` or the NMH `mailx`.  The latter re-spells the `-c` option as `-cc` but has no equivalent for `-b`.  The former has no direct equivalents for either, requiring that headers be injected using a generic mechanism.  (Note that, strictly speaking, `-b` and `-c` control *envelope* not headers, although the distinction between them is blurry at the level of `mailx`.)

## Further reading

- [`mailx`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/mailx.1posix.html).  Ubuntu 16.04 manual pages.
- [`mailx`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.html).  Ubuntu 16.04 manual pages.
- [`mailx`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/bsd-mailx.1.html).  Ubuntu 16.04 manual pages.
- [`mailx`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.html).  Ubuntu 14.04 manual pages.
- [`s-nail`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/s-nail/s-nail.1.en.html).  User commands.  s-nail.  Debian manual pages.
- [`mailx`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/mailutils/mailx.1.en.html).  User commands.  GNU mail utils.  Debian manual pages.
- [`mailx`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/bsd-mailx/mailx.1.en.html).  General Commands Manual.  BSD mailx.  Debian manual pages.
- [`mailx`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/nmh/mailx.1.en.html).  User commands.  NMH.  Debian manual pages.
- [Difference between mail and mailx?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89530/)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/469833/5132

Comment: See the thing is none of the mail service was pre installed on ubuntu,I explicitly installed gnu mailutils ,so what you suggest in my case ????